# Given two increasing divergent sequences $a_n, b_n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty e^{-ta_i}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty e^{-tb_i}$ is it true that $a_n=b_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemannian-geometry, spectral-theory

> Given two strictly increasing and divergent sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that the series
> $\sum_{i=1}^\infty e^{-ta_i}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty e^{-tb_i}$ converge
> and are equal for every $t>0$, is it true that $a_n=b_n$ for every
> $n$?

This problem arised while I was studying some spectral geometry (and more specifically in an exercise where I'm required to prove that two compact riemannian manifolds with the same heat trace are isospectral). I tried to remove all of the details that seemed unnecessary to make this problem accessible to a broader audience, so there is some possibility that the statement of the problem is wrong.

I would be happy also with a counterexample.

Comment: Notice that $$\sum_{i=k}^\infty e^{-ta_i}\sim e^{-ta_k}$$ What happens if  $a_k\ne b_k$?

Comment: I guess your $\sim$ is true in some sense, but how to we justify that? @C-RAM

Comment: @C-RAM Your claim is true provided the sequences are strictly increasing. Otherwise you have to take into account repetitions of the values of sequences.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc You're right. I'm assuming "increasing" means strictly increasing, but it's somewhat ambiguous. I myself use "non-decreasing" to denote the alternative case. I'll wait for clarification

Comment: I would substitute $x=e^{-t},$ so the approximate values at $x\to 0^+$ is determined by $a_1$ times the repetition number as it may occur that $a_1=\ldots =a_k.$ Then the approximate value at $0$ is $kx^{a_1}.$ Similarly for the second function the approximate value is equal $lx^{b_1}.$ Hence $a_1=b_1$ and $k=l.$ Now we can subtract the first parts from both functions and continue showing that the sequences are equal for indices larger than $k.$

Comment: @ArcticChar To respond and to give OP a more rigorous approach with limits, we can appeal to the dominated convergence theorem, (for simplicity, we only allow $t$ to take integer values, which is all we need for this problem) $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty }e^{ta_k}\sum_{i=k}^\infty e^{-ta_i}=\sum_{i=k}^\infty\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{-t(a_i-a_k)}=1$$ or equivalently, $$\sum_{i=k}^\infty e^{-ta_i}\sim e^{-ta_k}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If you have an positive increasing divergent sequence $\left(c_n\right)$ such that $\sum e^{-c_nt}$ converges for all $t > 0$,

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \sum_{n}e^{-c_kt} = 0$$

Let $g(t) = \sum_n e^{-c_nt}$ this function in a non increasing function so it is enough to prove that $g(m)\to 0$ for integers $m$. Or you can see that $g(m+1) \le e^{-c_1} g(m)$ So by induction, $g(m) \le g(1)e^{-c_1(m-1)} \to 0$

Answer (score 0):

We'll prove by induction on $k\geq 0$ that $a_k=b_k$. Both the basis of the induction and the inductive step are proved in the same way so let's prove the inductive step. Let's suppose that $a_i=b_i$ for every $i\leq k-1$, therefore
$$\sum_{j=k}^\infty e^{-a_j t}=\sum_{j=k}^\infty e^{-b_j t} \ \ \ \text{for every $t>0$. }$$
This implies that:
$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{j=k}^\infty e^{-a_j t}}{\sum\limits_{j=k}^\infty e^{-b_j t}}=1 $$
and since the sequences $(a_j)_{j\geq 0}$ and $(b_j)_{j\geq 0}$ are strictly increasing, we have
$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{e^{-a_k t}}{ e^{-b_k t}}=1 $$
and this concludes the proof.

Comment: Can you elaborate why the strict monotony implies that $\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{e^{-a_k t}}{ e^{-b_k t}}=1$?

Comment: While this is probably true it feels like saying "because the result is true, the result is true". There is no justification for why we should be able to ignore the other terms due to the limit and that is essentially the main part of the question.

Comment: To fill in the gap, consider $f(t) = \sum_{j=k+1}^\infty e^{-(a_j-a_k)t}$ which exists for $t > 0$ by assumption.  Show that $0 \leq f(t_0+t) \leq e^{-(a_{k+1}-a_k)t}f(t_0)$ so that $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t) = 0$.